# how to check if a date is missing from a list?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have an Excel worksheet that has a list of dates

```
Thursday, May 30, 2013
Friday, May 31, 2013
Monday, June 3, 2013
Tuesday, June 4, 2013
Wednesday, June 5, 2013
Thursday, June 6, 2013
Friday, June 7, 2013
Tuesday, June 11, 2013
Wednesday, June 12, 2013
Thursday, June 13, 2013
Friday, June 14, 2013
Monday, June 17, 2013
Tuesday, June 18, 2013
```

I  need to determine if I am missing a date (Weekday only) and insert it with a different color background.

I tried this

```
=IF(A2=A1+1,"","Missing next day")
```

But it tells me that Saturday is missing (and I am not interested in a weekend).

In the sample data above, **Monday June 10** is missing

Comment: So why not add an if() to trap Fridays and add 3 in that case...

Comment: But you should also look at the roll-over from the end of the month...

Comment: @urdearboy please make that an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @SolarMike stated:

```
=IF(A2=A1+(WEEKDAY(A1)=6)*2+1,"","Missing next day")
```

[image]

Comment: Neat, but the label should be missing day as it is before the Tuesday..

Comment: @SolarMike I just used what the OP had.

Answer (score 2):

This is something to get you started with [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) , as far as you are willing to change the colors as well:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim myCell As Range

    For Each myCell In Range("A1:A12")'One less, because it checks the cell on the next row
        Select Case Weekday(myCell)

        Case vbFriday
            If Weekday(myCell.Offset(1)) <> vbMonday Then
                myCell.Offset(0, 1) = "Missing!"
                myCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
        Case vbSaturday, vbSunday
            myCell.Offset(0, 1) = "Not interested"
        Case Else
            If Weekday(myCell.Offset(1)) - 1 <> Weekday(myCell) Then
                myCell.Offset(0, 1) = "Missing!"
                myCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
        End Select

    Next myCell

End Sub
```

[image]

The code uses the `WeekDay` function, which returns numbers based on  the week. Thus if the date is on Monday, it returns 2, when it is called like this: `Weekday("21.05.2018")`. Thus, one can make use the predefined enum `vbMonday`, which returns `2`.

Based on this, `Select Case` and `If` operators are introduced, taking care of the 3 cases - `vbFriday`, `vbSaturday, vbSunday` and the 4 other days.

In case that `Else` is not what is expected, then the interior becomes `vbYellow`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the equation you are looking for.

```
=If(A2=WORKDAY.INTL(A1,1),"","Missing Next Day")
```

You can also build in a database of holidays that you want to exclude from the search. You can put the table on another sheet and name the range of your table, and then include that named range at the end of workday equation. If you name the range "Holidays", the equation would be updated as follows:

```
=If(A2=WORKDAY.INTL(A1,1,Holidays),"","Missing Next Day")
```